# Hyperledger Vs Ethereum for supply chain management?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, bitcoin, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Which is the best blockchain development platform (Hyperledger/Ethereum) for supply chain management?

Comment: Hi there. Questions that ask for the "best" something-or-other usually get flagged as opinion-based: the answers you'll get are likely to be subjective, leading to drawn out discussion. It might be better to ask and discuss this on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching this myself for the last few weeks. The short answer to your question is that Hyperledger is fundamentally superior to ethereum for this use case.

With ethereum, you are not in control of your network. Every update, every state change of an asset will cost you money. Furthermore, the status of your supply chain (assuming you're using ethereum to asset track) will be completely public which for many companies is inexcusable. And lastly, if there was a mistake or a problem with your supply chain, you would not have the power to easily amend the problem. With ethereum, you do not control your infrastructure.

Hyperledger on the other hand is a private ledger system with a robust framework for crafting transactions. Since it's private, your data will not be public and you do not have to depend on mining to update your network. [IBM released their findings on using Hyperledger for supply chain](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-adopting-blockchain-for-enterprise-asset-management-eam/index.html), and they suggest using a model dubbed "Proof-of-existance" which would work much better than PoW since transactions could be backed by something that proves that the state change occured (shipping or financial documents). Not to mention updating your state of the supply chain would not cost anything. That alone would invalidate the ethereum candidate.

Comment: After usign both Hyperledger & Ethereum for a while, I prefer Hyperledger too, it's more light weight & easy to use.

Comment: the issue is hyperledger is far less secure and, much like contemporary supply chain solutions, is, in itself, a single point of failure (even within a consortium model, as companies have not yet warmed up to multi-stakeholder supply chain ownership that would be required for consortiums to work as intended). Most companies will create hyperledger systems within themselves, which, to the point of immutability and avoiding tampering, I think is their biggest weak point. However, the lack of tx costs and development simplicity certainly does help them as a candidate